# How to read and output XML processing instructions in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I'm writing a small Scala app that does the following:

1) Read XML/XHTML files

2) Do some minor pre-processing

3) Transform it with a XSLT stylesheet, if required.

4) Post-process it slightly.

5) Save it as XHTML.

My XML files would start with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xslt/default.xslt"?>
```

If I read them with

```
scala.xml.XML.load(scala.xml.Source.fromFile(file))
```

I get an Elem, but I loose the XML processing instructions. I resorted to reading it as String, doing String manipulation to find the xml-stylesheet, and then passing it to

```
scala.xml.XML.load(scala.xml.Source.fromString(text))
```

There must be a better way of doing this. I need to know which stylesheet I should use **inside Scala** because Scala has to call the XSLT processor, if needed.

Also, after I'm done processing them, I save them using

```
scala.xml.Utility.trim(transformed).buildString(true)
```

but the resulting document does not contain the XML declaration, nor the HTML DOCTYPE. I want to have those too.

I know that this is technically two questions, but those are basically both ends of the same problem, and I suspect that the solution to the second problem is related to the solution of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Scala's XML is inadequate for your needs. Even with `xml.parsing.XhtmlParser`, which generates a `Document`, you'd only get version, encoding, and dtd. You could make a contructing parser, an event parser or override XML with a custom SAXParser to get the XSLT stuff, but you'd still not be able to represent that information with Scala XML, and you'd still have to hand code your save to append that stuff back.

So I suggest you keep with one of the Java libraries that handles XSLT.

Comment: I cannot imagine that a modern plrogramming language doesn't have functions/API for evaluating an XPath expression! Good to know that Scala falls in this group.

Comment: @Dimitre No, it's just a failure of understanding on your part. Scala XML - ie, the standard XML library in Scala - does not support XPath. It supports monadic comprehensions over XML, which most XML libraries do not. So, if you want XPath, you'll need to use a library that does. Scala, the language, has many such libraries available.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for explaining. I'll know not to use Scala.

Comment: @Dimitre Built-in XML support in Scala is a mixed bag. But you can of course use all the existing (and consistently horrible) Java APIs as well out of the box. As for me I can't imagine using anything but XPath 2.0, which means directly using Saxon anyway.

Comment: @ebruchez: Yes, I imagine that if I were bound to use Java, my choice would be Saxon (though I have heard of other XPath 2.0 (only XPath) engines, such as PsychoPath).

Comment: @Dmitre BTW there is work on improving XML support in Scala: see the anti-xml project https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml